# AnyObject to array in swift

Tags: ios, swift

Following function is given:

```
class func collection(#response: NSHTTPURLResponse,
                       representation: AnyObject) -> [City] {
    return []
}
```

So this function should return an array of city objects. I have to somehow transform the `representation` variable that is of type AnyObject to a city array.

I don't know what the exact type of representation is but I can do things like

```
println(representation[0])
```

and it will print the object. Any ideas how to transform representation to [City] array?

### Update

Doing

```
println(representation as [City])
```

prints nil.

City.swift:

```
final class City : ResponseCollectionSerializable {

    let id: String
    let name: String

    class func collection(#response: NSHTTPURLResponse, representation: AnyObject) -> [City] {
        return []
    }
}
```

This is just copy and pasted from https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#generic-response-object-serialization It should serialize a JSON response into objects:

```
@objc public protocol ResponseCollectionSerializable {
    class func collection(#response: NSHTTPURLResponse, representation: AnyObject) -> [Self]
}

extension Alamofire.Request {

    public func responseCollection<T: ResponseCollectionSerializable>(completionHandler: (NSURLRequest, NSHTTPURLResponse?, [T]?, NSError?) -> Void) -> Self {
        let serializer: Serializer = { (request, response, data) in
            let JSONSerializer = Request.JSONResponseSerializer(options: .AllowFragments)
            let (JSON: AnyObject?, serializationError) = JSONSerializer(request, response, data)
            if response != nil && JSON != nil {
                return (T.collection(response: response!, representation: JSON!), nil)
            } else {
                return (nil, serializationError)
            }
        }

        return response(serializer: serializer, completionHandler: { (request, response, object, error) in
            completionHandler(request, response, object as? [T], error)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: representation as [City] maybe. but i think you should find out representation's actual class first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `representation` parameter you're getting back is the result of a call to `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData...`, so it's either a `NSArray` or a `NSDictionary`. Since you get a value for `representation[0]`, we know it's an `NSArray`. Exactly what your code looks like will depend on the JSON (a sample of which you should include in a question like this), but your code will need to be something like (untested code ahead):

```
class func collection(#response: NSHTTPURLResponse, representation: AnyObject) -> [City] {
    var cities: [City] = []
    for cityRep in representation {
        // these next two lines should grab the city data using the correct key
        let id = cityRep.valueForKey("cityID") as String
        let name = cityRep.valueForKey("cityName") as String
        // now add the city to our list
        cities.append(City(id: id, name: name))
    } 
    return cities
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming (and although I hate to make assumptions, your question is a bit vague about the details) that the representation is either an NSData object that represents the response, or an Array that you have created from the response.

In my experience, such a response is an array of dictionaries that you can use to create city objects. So you need to write a function that transforms this dictionary into a `City` object. Something with the signature:

```
parser (AnyObject) -> City
```

Now, you could just iterate through the array, apply this function to each dictionary, collect the results into an Array and return the result.

But you could be classier and map your function over the array and return the result.